# Purpose of workers and workQueue in threadpoolexecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

As per my understanding ThreadpoolExecutor has two main data structure(workers,workQueue) for managing tasks.worker(Set) has threads that will keep running till executor shutdown and workerQueue keeps all tasks coming to executor. But as per code i do not see all tasks are being added in workQueue.task is added in queue only at line no 1361 that will not be executed in every case.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @GKR OP is referring to the jdk source code

Answer (score 6):

Actually no, `workQueue` does not in fact keep all the tasks submitted to the executor. Here is the main portion of `#execute(Runnable)` (using [this](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java.html) as a reference, you may be using the fernflower decompiled source or a different version or whatever);

```
 1323           int c = ctl.get();
 1324           if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
 1325               if (addWorker(command, true))
 1326                   return;
 1327               c = ctl.get();
 1328           }
 1329           if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
 1330               int recheck = ctl.get();
 1331               if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
 1332                   reject(command);
 1333               else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
 1334                   addWorker(null, false);
 1335           }
 1336           else if (!addWorker(command, false))
 1337               reject(command);
```

There are 3 steps to this code:

1. Check if the executor can add a worker. If it can, use a new worker
2. If not, try to add it to the `workQueue`
3. If all else fails, reject

The case concerning your question is the first step, in which the code returns before adding anything. In fact, that is not the case, the constructor for `Worker` has a runnable parameter, which is its first task. Whenever TPE adds a new worker the runnable submitted is the first task run in that worker. The `#runWorker(Worker)` method will run the first task if it is found, or wait for there to be tasks in the aforementioned `workQueue`.